# Definition of simple spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-curves, classical-mechanics

From the book "Spinning Tops" by Audin, given Lax equation $[A_{\lambda},B_{\lambda}]$ where $\lambda$ is a parameter (so called spectral parameter), she claims that we have spectral curve $P(\lambda,\nu)=0$ where $P(\lambda,\nu)$ is a characteristic polynomial of $A_{\lambda}$. Then, she talks about when $A_{\lambda}$ has a simple spectrum. I tried to look for definition of it, but I couldn't find it. Can you please tell me what does it mean for a spectrum to be simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect she means that the eigenvalues are all simple, i.e. the characteristic polynomial has no multiple roots.

Comment: Or an $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.